# How to use polygon collision detection with Arcade Physics Engine in Phaser 3

Tags: game-development, phaser-framework, phaserjs

I'm currently working on a side scrolling game project using Phaser 3 and the Arcade Physics Engine. However, I've encountered a challenge regarding collision detection with polygon shapes. I'd like to incorporate polygon collision support into my game without having to switch to another physics engine like Matter.js. Is there a way to achieve this within the confines of the Arcade Physics Engine?

I understand that the Arcade Physics Engine primarily supports basic shapes like rectangles and circles for collision detection. However, my game requires more complex polygon shapes for collisions.

I've explored various resources and documentation but haven't found a straightforward solution. Can anyone provide guidance or share insights on how to implement polygon collision detection while still utilizing the Arcade Physics Engine? Any tips, code snippets, or recommended practices would be greatly appreciated.

To reiterate, the goal is to integrate polygon collision detection seamlessly into a Phaser 3 game that relies on the Arcade Physics Engine, avoiding the need for a complete overhaul or migration to a different physics engine.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that comes to mind is to use the `processCallback` function of the `collide` or the `overlap` function. ([link to the documentation](https://newdocs.phaser.io/docs/3.55.2/Phaser.Physics.Arcade.ArcadePhysics#overlap))
In this callback function you could calculate if an object has collided with an other object, if so return `true` and than the `collideCallback` is called, if not return `false`and no collision has occured.

With other words you would have to do all the heavy lifting of checking for collision between the objects, polygons or ..., that are passed to the  `processCallback` function.

Apart from this I don't know easy way out-of-the-box to achieve this with arcade physics, but I'm by all means no expert.

> And this would still use the "normal" phaser Arcade physics system, since this callback is perfect for more granular/specific collision detection.

**Btw.:** you could check if there are some plugins, that add this functionality (you could checkout https://phaserplugins.com/, https://rexrainbow.github.io/phaser3-rex-notes/docs/site/plugin-list/ , but you have to be careful some plugins out there are for phaser 2/CE )

**Here a very basic example, how this could work:**
*(I'm not sure, if this is the most efficient way to do it, but it only a demo)*

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';
console.clear();

var config = {
    width: 536,
    height: 183,
    physics: {
        default: 'arcade',
        arcade: {            
            gravity:{ y: 20 },
            debug: true
        }
    },
    scene: { create },
}; 

function create () {
    this.add.text(10,10, 'Wait for the collision')
        .setScale(1.5)
        .setOrigin(0)
        .setStyle({fontStyle: 'bold', fontFamily: 'Arial'});

    let graphics  = this.make.graphics();
    graphics.fillStyle(0xffffff);
    graphics.fillRect(0, 0, 10, 10);
    graphics.generateTexture('img', 10, 10);
    
    const points = [ 10,10, 30,0, 50,10, 70,50, 20,40, 0,80 ];

    const object1 = this.add.polygon(170, 10, points, 0x6666ff).setOrigin(0);
    
    this.physics.add.existing( object1 );
    
    const object2 = this.physics.add.staticImage(200, 100, 'img')
    
    this.physics.add.collider(object1, object2, 
      // collideCallback to indicate collision
      (obj1, obj2) => {
          obj2.setTint(0xff0000);
      }, 
      // processCallback decides when it counts as a real collisio 
      (obj1, obj2) => {
          // move helper polyon to the correct position
          let poly = Phaser.Geom.Polygon.Translate(new Phaser.Geom.Polygon(points), obj1.x, obj1.y)

          // check other Points
          let topLeft = obj2.getTopLeft();
          let topRight = obj2.getTopRight();

          // some other Tests
          return Phaser.Geom.Polygon.Contains( poly, topLeft.x, topLeft.y) || Phaser.Geom.Polygon.Contains( poly, topRight.x, topRight.y);
      });
}


new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, i agree that use the `processCallback` function to detect polygon collide is good solution. But detect overlap is easier than detect collide and more important is need to separate 2 object (or more if multiple polygon collide character object). I have used [SAT](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sat) to detect collide, overlap axes, separate object but it not totally smooth like matter. I also tried to use raycaster to detect collide position of object and polygon but same as above, i can't separate them smoothly

Comment: Yes, I assume `overlap` might be the better solution, but for the demo it was easier for me to use `collider`. I don't understand what you mean with separate two objects. In any case it depends on you exact usecase on what would be the best solution/workaround.

Comment: Actually, in arcade physics engine, when 2 objects collide/overlap, arcade will `separate` these objects to make them will not overlap. For easy to understand, you can imagine `separate` will make mario can stand on ground/brick without overlap with object or pass through. This method have been implemented [here](https://github.com/phaserjs/phaser/blob/4fea76252b28a21fc3ca2bed1d48588c4ef5a3d7/src/physics/arcade/World.js#L1353) This is goal point of this task

Comment: Okay I see now what you mean, but this is not possible with this method since the objects already overlap, you would have to write your own seperation code, since you would be overrideing the collision/overlaping code / check. Thats why I mean depenting on the usecase one would have to adapt. (like deactivation the body, and/or removing temporary the collision checks, and/or changing temporary the body bound box size, .... In any case trying to hack arcade physics will entail, some compromises or alot of coding.

Comment: I have replaced and customized a bit in separate method of arcade physics and integrate SAT to check collide, in some basic case, it works, but in some other case, it set character wrong position. You can see my example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/phaser3-typescript-h2pd9m?file=game%2Ftilemap.scene.ts). Very welcome if you can point out my misstake

Comment: Very nice solution the only reason why it might set the character in the wrong position in the posted demo, is because you are only testing top collision (on line 147+), it seems to work well if the other collision check are also activated. I think your solution looks really good.

Comment: Actually that is what i want, the polygon only block top line, other direction can pass. In some case it will display weird position of character like [this](https://ibb.co/CmWB4MZ). Idk what am i miss

Comment: Yes that wierd position just happens because the player can jump in between of the body, and if you test if the player can enter the body from the left, this won't happen. Or you could tweak the `bias` on the line 264. Make it bigger 10 might work in this specific case.